# Domain Layer and BDD

Tags: bdd, specflow

Has anyone used BDD for driving their domain Layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we have found this process to have worked very well and used specflow to deliver this approach fairly easy. We have over 2000+ scenarios implemented in our domain layer alone and we have also used this approach for testing our controllers in our UI layer too(another 2000+ tests).

It's a good idea if working on a large project to put some thought into how to organise the steps before you start as you will quickly start to collect a large amount of steps and finding a step can become a bit of a challenge.

The biggest issue we had was having multiple people on a team writing scenarios, they would often write the same step but with a slightly different wording resulting in the same step being added twice.

Comment: Multiple wording is not usually a problem. Most of the tools use a mapping from plain text onto the methods themselves, in C# this is usually via attributes where you can specify either more than one and use regexes to match. See Step definitons section of https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although lately we've been looking at Cuke and Specification by Example as a higher level to start driving from. See http://specificationbyexample.com/

Comment: Then will your specfication has UI included

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ***that's*** what it's for!

I've found BDD main benefits is how it, in a natural way, lets you;

1. Drive the design (plan then do)
2. Discover and emphasize the domains ubiquitous language
3. Document project progress and current state (specs maps to stories and sprint plans)

If it also results in acceptance or unit tests that's great but I think most value comes out of the above. It also helps new team members get a grip on things and it's very easy to return to projects domain mentally after being away for a while.

I also agree on before mentioned "step-duplication" problems, it's well spent time refactoring and consolidating steps trying to keep them well-structured.